# How can i convert .outerHTML to .text()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to convert `item.outerHTML` to `.text()`, Actually I want to convert the html to text, now what do I do ?

```
$(imgAttr).each(function(index,item) {
 var valImg = $(item).attr("alt");
 if (typeof valImg == typeof undefined || valImg == "") {           
     $(".url-res").append(item.outerHTML.text());
 }
```

});

Comment: Try this: `if (typeof valImg === 'undefined' || valImg == "") {...`

Comment: what's the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Generate a div with the outerhtml as it's html property using jQuery, then use `text()` with that object.

```
$('.ele').each(function(index, item) {
  var valImg = $(item).attr("alt");
  if (typeof valImg == "undefined" || valImg == "") {
    // -------------------^------ you can use "undefined` here
    $(".url-res").append($('<div/>', {
      html: item.outerHTML
    }).text());
  }
});
```

Or you can use `outerText` property

```
$('.ele').each(function(index, item) {
  var valImg = $(item).attr("alt");
  if (typeof valImg == "undefined" || valImg == "") {
    // -------------------^------ you can use "undefined` here
    $(".url-res").append(item.outerText).text());
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

i think if condition is not being satisfied try below one

```
$(imgAttr).each(function(index,item) {
 var valImg = $(item).attr("alt");
 if (typeof valImg ==='undefined' || valImg == "") {           
     $(".url-res").append(item.outerHTML.text());
 }
});
```

Comment: You think... Have you checked yourself? "Thinking" should be solely replied in comments :)